# Counterexample/correctness check for equality of two functions

Tags: limits, inequality

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two real valued functions of $x$. I am able to show that for any choice of $\delta > 0$ and all $x$,

$$f(x) \leq g(x) + \delta$$

I am also able to show that for all $x$

$$g(x) \leq f(x)$$

Is this sufficient to conclude that $f(x) = g(x)$? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Yes it is. Fix $x$ and take the limit $\delta\to 0^+$(actually you don't even need limits; if equality did not hold you can easily try to derive a contradiction by taking $\delta = f(x) - g(x)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're uncomfortable about the limiting process, suppose they are not equal; then $f(x) = g(x) + \epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon$ (since you already know $g \le f$). Then take $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Then we have

$$f(x) \le g(x) + \delta$$

for all positive $ \delta$. With $ \delta \to 0+$ we get

$$f(x) \le g(x).$$